# Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder incompatible with Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData .NET5.0

Tags: azure, nuget, odata, microsoft.aspnetcore.odata

I have a .NET5 OData project that I am trying to deploy to an Azure App Service. My project uses Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData version 8.0.8, which supports .NET5.

I am getting the following error in my Azure pipeline:

> Package Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder 1.0.8 is not compatible with
> net50 (.NETFramework,Version=v5.0). Package
> Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder 1.0.8 supports:
> - net60 (.NETFramework,Version=v6.0)
> - netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

When I review the Nuget packages, it states that Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder does not support .NET5, but Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData does support .NET5, and depends on Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder
[image]

You can see that Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder does not support .NET5.
[image]

How am I supposed to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData with a .NET5 application when it's dependencies do not support .NET5?

And none of the previous versions of Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder support .NET5. I don't see how I can get this to work even with an earlier version.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since I didn't receive any feedback, I was force to upgrade my web project to .NET6. Afterwards, I updated Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData to the latest version, where both Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData and Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder support .NET6.